# Pause multimedia in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, android-webview

I want to pause audio and video in android WebView without interrupting the rendering of the page.

I have tried following things but either it didn't work for me it pauses rendering of the entire WebView or the sound keeps playing.

```
webView.onPause()
```

Another method

```
Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView")
                            .getMethod("onPause", (Class[]) null)
                            .invoke(webView, (Object[]) null);
```

Tried the below thing it also did not work.

```
val audioPauseJavascipt = "function pauseAudioAndVideo(windowA){" +
                    "    for(var i = 0; i < windowA.document.getElementsByTagName('video').length; i++){" +
                    "        var media = windowA.document.getElementsByTagName('video')[i];" +
                    "       media.pause(); " +
                    "       media.currentTime = -1; " +
                    "       media.volume = 0; " +
                    "    }" +
                    "    for(var i = 0; i < windowA.document.getElementsByTagName('audio').length; i++){" +
                    "        var media = windowA.document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[i];" +
                    "       media.pause(); " +
                    "       media.currentTime = -1; " +
                    "       media.volume = 0; " +
                    "    }" +
                                "   <!-- for(var i = 0; i < windowA.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe').length; i++){" +
                    "        var iframeA = windowA.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[i];" +
                    "        pauseAudioAndVideo(iframeA.contentWindow);    " +
                    "    } -->" +
                    "}" +
            "pauseAudioAndVideo(this.window);";
mWebView.evaluateJavascript(audioPauseJavascipt, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `windowA` hasn't finished loading, the elements you're looking for by name (`audio`, `video`, and `iframe`) may not be present when your script runs. You can use a [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event to execute your script when the document has been fully parsed, and while other content (images, etc.) is still loading:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    mWebView.evaluateJavascript(audioPauseJavascipt, null)
});
```